# I have an AWS EC2 instance. I want to download a few Python packages, but I want to scan each package/file before they are installed. Any ideas how?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, package, scanning

To prevent supply chain attacks and to follow the best form of security, I want to scan each package file (as packages have been seen to have malwares these days). Can anyone name any application or github project or something by which this can be accomplished?

I tried finding about automated scans, but haven't found much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I'm running this command 'sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y' , I want all the downloaded files to be automatically scanned for malwares. Any idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use AWS Inspector to scan packages on your EC2. You would need to install SSM agent on your EC2. Thing is that Inspector can only scan OSes supported by Systems Manager.

More info about AWS Inspector scanning [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/user/scanning-ec2.html)

Info about supported systems [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/operating-systems-and-machine-types.html#prereqs-operating-systems)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will surely try AWS Inspector. Is there a similar solution for Azure? I have a couple of Azure VMs too where i want to do the same.